# Phonegap Function returning wrong figures when called in a Database callback

Tags: javascript, iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using JQM and Phonegap. I have a function which calculates distance between two points.
I am doing this in Xcode and gave the simulator lat = 51.4863 long = -3.179169

```
distance = function(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit) 
{ 
    var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180;
    var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180;
    var radlon1 = Math.PI * lon1/180;
    var radlon2 = Math.PI * lon2/180;
    var theta = lon1-lon2;
    var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180;
    var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
    dist = Math.acos(dist);
    dist = dist * 180/Math.PI;
    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    dist = dist * 1.609344;
    if (unit=="M") { dist = dist / 1.609344 ;}
    if (unit=="N") { dist = dist * 0.8684 ;}
    alert(dist);
    return dist;
}
```

I also have a database of locations which i want to return distances from.

distance function returns a wrong number if it is called from the onsuccess callback of my db.transactions executeSQL.

However, when i call this function on the success callback of getCurrentPosition it works fine. bear in mind that i am also running a SQL Select Query here to.

My code for when the function is working is below:

```
$( document ).delegate("#mfinder", "pageinit", function() {

  var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "location Data", 200000);
  db.transaction(inputData, errorCB, inputDataSuccess);
});

function inputData(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS locations');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE locations (id UNIQUE, name, lat, lon, pcode)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO locations VALUES (1, "My house", 51.4863, -3.179169, "E20QP")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO locations VALUES (2, "Manchester", 51.548577,0.708275, "ABC123")');
}

function inputDataSuccess() {
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "location Data", 200000);
    db.transaction(readLocations, errorCB);
}

function readLocations(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('select * from locations', [], getDistance, errorCB);
}

function getDistance (tx, r){
    d1 = r.rows.item(1).lat;
    d2 = r.rows.item(1).lon;
    d3 = r.rows.item(1).name;
}

$("#fm").click(function() {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
});

function onSuccess(position) {
    clat = position.coords.latitude;
    clon = position.coords.longitude;
    var x = distance(clat, clon, d1, d2, "M");
    alert(x); //THIS WORKS!
}
```

and when the function returns wrong figure, my code is like this:

```
clat = 0;
clon = 0;
$("#fm").click(function() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "location Data", 200000);
    db.transaction(inputData, errorCB, inputDataSuccess);
});

function onSuccess(position) {
    clat = position.coords.latitude;
    clon = position.coords.longitude;
}

function inputData(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS locations');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE locations (id UNIQUE, name, lat, lon, pcode)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO locations VALUES (1, "My house", 51.4863, -3.179169, "E20QP")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO locations VALUES (2, "Manchester", 51.548577,0.708275, "ABC123")');
}

function inputDataSuccess() {
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "location Data", 200000);
    db.transaction(readLocations, errorCB);
}

function readLocations(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('select * from locations', [], getDistance, errorCB);
}

function getDistance (tx, r){
    d1 = r.rows.item(1).lat;
    d2 = r.rows.item(1).lon;
    d3 = r.rows.item(1).name;
var milesAway = distance(clat, clon, d1, d2, "M"); //wrong figures!!!
alert(milesAway);
}
```

The first way it works and goes something like this.... In the PageInit i am creating the data and also selecting the data into memory. Then the 'click' function will enable the location service and do a distance function.

2nd scenario is nothing hapens on pageinit, everything is on the Click event. Here, I retrive the users position first, then, i run of the database and get one data row back to calculate disdance.

Now, can someone tell me why i am getting wrong figures??? ideally, i would like the second codebase to work, that way, i can loop through loads of data to append to DIV elements for example. Many thanks for anyone looking at my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it is because you are not calling your code in an async manner. You are expecting that clat and clon to be set before your DB transaction is executed. Since the call to getPosition is async it probably returns after your getDistance method thereby giving you incorrect results. Try setting it up so that in your onSuccess method after you set clat and clon that you call window.openDatabase and db.transaction(). That should get you the correct results.

Comment: I set up a transaction to Select * after i set clat and clon, then a call back to run distance function. Didnt work, still getting wrong results. But your on the right track lol. thanks for pointing out about async. learnt something new.